# Google workspace hidden admin email address

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I am using Google Workspace mainly for having all my emails in one place with custom domains and other external email addresses forwarding to the central Google Workspace account.

This is an individual account with a single user (me). I have my account as the only user that I also use for my email.

I would like to know if there is a way to have my admin user with a random email address/username and have that email that I use to login to Google Workspace hidden from the public? In a sense, I would like to have a unique-hard-to-guess username/email to log in to Google Workspace/Gmail that is not used anywhere and it's not exposed to the public world as I interact with other people.

As of now, that email that I use to log in to my Google Workspace account will be visible as a contact to other people and I don't think I can change it to private.

Think of a secret username, so anyone who knows my aliases (the emails I communicate with the world) they won't be able to use those aliases to log in to my Google Workspace.

Is anyone aware of something like that?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "as I interact with other people"? Will you be using the "hidden admin" to interact to other people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it not answers directly your question I think that you should start by reading [Set admin privileges to protect user privacy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10159640?hl=en)

---

You can disable most of the Google services for the "hidden admin" to prevent that this email address to be accidentally leaked through one of them and to prevent communication with it including Gmail, Chat, Hangouts, etc. For details see [Turn a service on or off for Google Workspace users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182442?hl=en).

Also you can hide the "hidden email" address from the Google Workspace Directory. For details see [Hide a user from the Directory](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1285988?hl=en)

One way to proceed is to create an organization unit (OU) first for the "hidden admin", turn off all the not required services on this OU then create the "hidden admin" account on this OU.